# PowerPivot Filtering on Any or All

Tags: powerpivot

I have a table as shown in the image. I need to create two filters in PowerPivot:

```
Group1Member_On_Any_Day: Set to 1 if any record in Group1MemberFlag is set to 1
Group1Member_On_All_Days: Set to 1 if all records in Group1MemberFlag is set to 1
```

The problems that I am running into are:

1. How do I filter on an aggregate
2. How do I ensure the aggregate filters are applied as I slice my
   table by date or CustomerId

CustomerMembershipTable
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a Eureka moment and realized that the filtering has to be done in the measure and that measure should be used to view the aggregations. For example, if I wanted to count customers who are a member of Group1, I would create a measure as follows:

Cnt_Customer_In_Group1:=Calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT([CustomerId]),FILTER('CustomerTable',[Group1MemberFlag]=1))

If you also have a measure that counts distinct CustomerIds, you can a filter on Group1MemberFlag to see which customerIds are in Group1 and which are not in Group1.